# Smooth Scrolling - Not scrolling all the way to the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website that I've decided to use smooth scrolling with a fixed sidebar navigation. But suddenly when I started adding content it does not scroll all the way down to my #contact anchor tag. Any ideas why it would do this? It seems to be an issue across IE, FF, and Chrome.

http://encorevisions.com/proofsites/finaldrive/

Answer (score 0):

All the `<li>` elements in `#females` are floated. Because there are no non-floating elements after the list in that section it ends right after the `<h2>`.
This is where the section `#contact` begins and where you anchor makes you scroll to.

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on the list elements or add an element with `clear: both;` after the list to address this issue.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid I wasn't seeing. That's what I get for working too late at night. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be something wrong in the  div #females is there any floating? if not why is there a clear:both on the end.

I believe there is something wrong with floating because if you firebug your site and hover the div #females it seems like there is nothing in it. that mostly happens with floating and not clearing